# Selecting the first xml node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I've the following xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet xmlns="www.asdsad.com/sdsad">
  <Balances>
    <AccountNumber>KK-888</AccountNumber>
    <SubAccountNumber>KK-888-1</SubAccountNumber>
    <TAcctID>1</TAcctID>
    <TransactionAccount>ARC Deposit</TransactionAccount>
    <Description />
    <Balance>0.0000</Balance>
  </Balances>
  <Balances>
    <AccountNumber>KK-888</AccountNumber>
    <SubAccountNumber>KK-888-2</SubAccountNumber>
    <TAcctID>2</TAcctID>
    <TransactionAccount>Assessments and Dues</TransactionAccount>
    <Description>This is the primary account for all associations dues and assessments. </Description>
    <Balance>170</Balance>
  </Balances>
  <Balances>
    <AccountNumber>KK-888</AccountNumber>
    <SubAccountNumber>KK-888-4</SubAccountNumber>
    <TAcctID>4</TAcctID>
    <TransactionAccount>Fines/Compliance</TransactionAccount>
    <Description />
    <Balance>0.0000</Balance>
  </Balances>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need this result xml from above through xslt,

```
<balance amount="170" />
```

I'll pass the SubAccountNumber to the xslt and I need the particular Balances/Balance amount. In the above example I've passed the SubAccountNumber  value as "KC1-0221-2" so the second Balances node is matched and it's Balance value is "170". Can anyone help me to write the xslt for that. (Note: only one node will match the passed SubAccountNumber).

**UPDATED** I've no problem if I can produce the xml with a root node,

```
<account>
     <balance amount="170" />
</account>
```

Comment: How will you pass input? using parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:asd="www.asdsad.com/sdsad"
    exclude-result-prefixes="asd">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="SAN" select="'KC1-0221-2'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/asd:NewDataSet">
        <balance amount="{asd:Balances[asd:SubAccountNumber=$SAN]/asd:Balance}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will produce

```
<balance amount="" />
```

In the case `$SAN` is not present in the input document. Otherwise how you'd like to return in case of not matching at all?

Comment: The question also made mention of wanting the "first node", this answer doesn't address this part of the requirement.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: As usually happens, I think the question in the title does not really match the OP requ. However is just a matter of selecting the "first node", and we can easily tune the answer.